# OpenMP: why this application scale sometimes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to speedup the OpenCV SIFT algorithm with OpenMP on a `Intel® Core™ i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4`. You can find the code in [`sift.cpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp).

The most expensive part is the descriptor computaton, in particular:

```
static void calcDescriptors(const std::vector<Mat>& gpyr, const std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
                            Mat& descriptors, int nOctaveLayers, int firstOctave )
{
    int d = SIFT_DESCR_WIDTH, n = SIFT_DESCR_HIST_BINS;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < keypoints.size(); i++ )
    {
        KeyPoint kpt = keypoints[i];
        int octave, layer;
        float scale;
        unpackOctave(kpt, octave, layer, scale);
        CV_Assert(octave >= firstOctave && layer <= nOctaveLayers+2);
        float size=kpt.size*scale;
        Point2f ptf(kpt.pt.x*scale, kpt.pt.y*scale);
        const Mat& img = gpyr[(octave - firstOctave)*(nOctaveLayers + 3) + layer];

        float angle = 360.f - kpt.angle;
        if(std::abs(angle - 360.f) < FLT_EPSILON)
            angle = 0.f;
        calcSIFTDescriptor(img, ptf, angle, size*0.5f, d, n, descriptors.ptr<float>((int)i));
    }
}
```

**The serial version of this function take `52 ms` on average.**

This `for` has an high granulatiy: it's executed `604` times (which is keypoints.size() ). The main time consuming component inside the `for` is `calcSIFTDescriptor` which takes most of the cycle time computation and it takes on `105 us` on average, but it often happens that it can take `200us`or `50us`.

However, we are incredibly lucky: there is no dependency between each `for` cycle, so we can just add:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,8)
```

and obtain an initial speedup. The `dynamic` option is introduced since it seems it give little better performances than `static` (don't know why).

The problem is that **it's really unstable and doesn't scale**. This is the time needed to compute the function in parallel mode:

`25ms 43ms 32ms 15ms 27ms 53ms 21ms 24ms`

As you can see only once the optimal speedup in a quad-core system is reached (`15ms`). Most of the times we reach half of the optimal speedup:  `25ms` in a quadcore system is only half of the theoretical optimal speedup.

Why this happens? How can we improve this?

**UPDATE:**
As suggested in the comments, I tried to use a bigger dataset. Using an huge image, the serial version takes `13574ms` to compute the descriptors, while the parallel version `3704ms` with the same quad-core of before. Much better: even if it's not the best theoretical result, it actually scales well. But actually the problem remain, since the previous results are obtained from a typical image.

**UPDATE 1:** as suggested by the comment, I tried to benchmark without any interval between the execution in an "hot mode" (see comment for more details). Better results are achieved more frequently, but still there is a lot of variations. This are the times (in ms) for 100 runs in hot mode:

`43 42  14  26  14  43  13  26  15  51  15  20  14  40  34  15  15  31  15  22  14  21  17  15  14  27  14  16  14  22  14  22  15  15  14  43  16  16  15  28  14  24  14  36  15  32  13  21  14  23  14  15  13  26  15  35  13  32  14  36  14  34  15  40  28  14  14  15  15  35  15  22  14  17  15  23  14  24  17  16  14  35  14  29  14  25  14  32  14  28  14  34  14  30  22  14  15  24  14  31`

You can see a lot of good results (`14ms`, `15ms`) but a lot of horrible results also (`>40ms`). The average is `22ms` Notice that there is no at most `4ms` of variation in the sequential mode:

`52 54  52  52  51  52  52  53  53  52  53  51  52  53  53  54  53  53  53  53  54  53  54  54  53  53  53  52  53  52  51  52  52  53  54  54  54  55  55  55  54  54  54  53  53  52  52  52  51  52  54  53  54  54  54  55  54  54  52  55  52  52  52  51  52  51  52  52  51  51  52  52  53  53  53  53  55  54  55  54  54  54  55  52  52  52  51  51  52  51  51  51  52  53  53  54  53  54  53  55`

**UPDATE 2:**

I've noticed that each CPU utilization during the "hot mode" benchmarking is quite random and also it **never** reach more than 80%, as shown in the image below:

[image]

Instead the image below shows the CPUs utilization while I compile OpenCV through `make -j4`. As you can see it more stable and used almost 100% of it:

[image]

I think that this is variation in the first image are normal since we execute the same short program many times, which is more unstable than one big program. What I don't understand is **why we never reach more than 80% of CPU utilization**.

Comment: Could you give some test results on larger datasets ? Try to have it last a few seconds to get a better idea of the speed-up that isn't influenced by background processes or completely determined by the thread creation overhead.

Comment: Since the SIFT complexity is proportional to the image dimension, it's not so  easy to make the computation in order of seconds, but I'll see what I can do about it. Consider anyway that this data are based on a typical image and the algorithm is supposed to work with this dataset.

Comment: You could try to create a fake SIFT vector

Comment: Look at my update question :)

Comment: How do you benchmark. I sometimes give a cold and hot benchmark.  The cold one is the first time and the hot one is time after running once. The first iteration often takes more time.  You could also quote the median time.  The most honest time depends on what you're doing. If for example you wanted to quote a frame rate and let's say it was about 60 fps.  The time to render the first frame is not so interesting as all the rest so in this case I think it makes sense to throw out the cold time of the first frame.

Comment: Looks like you might have a load-balancing issue, as the variations of time for the call to `calcSIFTDescriptor()` suggest. I would encourage you to explore more `schedule` options, starting with `schedule(auto)`. `dynamic` with a smaller chunk size or `guided` might be good bets too...

Comment: @Zboson I think that I know what you mean, but actually this is kinda cheating :D The way that I benchmark is only in the "cold" mode: I run the program, the script pause for a while (let's say a second) and relunch the program. If I would relunch the program as soon it is finished, then the "hot" mode would give better performances problably, but this is not useful in an image applications (where we process just one image, or frame). I think that for this application your approach isn't valid.

Comment: @Zboson I updated the question, look **UPDATE 1**. Unfortunately, your stated problem is not the problem.

Comment: What compiler and OS are you using? Are you binding the threads? Set `OMP_PROCBIND` in the environment to true. Also, make sure that no other program is eating CPU time. A tool such as Intel VTune Amplifier (commercially licensed) or Thread Analyzer from Sun Studio, or even Score-P might give you an insight into where threads spend their time.

Comment: How do you measure the time? Windows time measurement isn't that fine-granulated, afaik.

Comment: @HristoIliev ubuntu 16, `OMP_PROCBIND` is `TRUE` by default, but executing `export OMP_PROCBIND=TRUE` didn't change nothing. Each CPU utilization is under 5%.

Comment: @Micka `gettimeofday()` which is pretty common and multi-core safe in Linux

Comment: Please give a look of section **UPDATE 2** where I talk about CPU utilization.

Comment: why did you choose chunk size 8? did you want 8 threads instead? According to https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-scheduling dynamic scheduling has additional overhead.

Comment: @Gilles I tried `schedule(dynamic,2) schedule(dynamic,1) schedule(dynamic,4) schedule(dynamic,8) schedule(dynamic,16) schedule(auto) schedule(guided,8)` and I achieved the best one with `schedule(dynamic,2)`

Comment: @Micka I know that doesn't mean 8 thread, but dynamic chunk of size 8. Look at my previous comment.

Comment: Problem seems still unsolved, especially for the high variation.

Comment: Do your cores share some cache (google says only L3 is shared)? Different keypoints will jump a lot in memory, different random caching behaviour might be randomly good or bad on different runs.

Comment: According to Feng at al: “Parallelization  and
characterization of sift on multi-core systems.” `memory bandwidth is a determining factor of SIFT performance.` (they achieved 10x to 11x speedup on a 16 core machine - others 6.2x on 8 core machines, etc). Maybe see "Accelerating SIFT on Parallel Architectures" from Wan et al, too.

Comment: @Micka do you know how can I get one of these implementations?

Comment: no, sorry. Maybe the research teams published them, but probably not.

Comment: is this tool available for your OS? http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/03/10/determining-whether-an-application-has-poor-cache-performance-2/

Comment: As mentioned several times before, this is a question best investigated with proper tool support. Ideally you want a tool that is aware of threads and captures the dynamics of the different iterations, like the ones mentioned by  Hristo Iliev. Unfortunately without a small reproducible example, there is not much we can do than guessing...

Comment: @Zulan sorry for the late answer. I'll give a look to the tool that you linked, but I thought that we didn't have control of cache memories mechanism. Anyway, what do you mean by 'without a small reproducible example, there is not much we can do than guessing...'? :)

Comment: 1) Well, some mechanism is responsible for sporadic good and bad performance. You can probably control/influence that mechanism. But first you have to figure out what exactly it is. 2) In general, it is bad to guess about performance. Measuring is always better. But we cannot easily measure the code you provided, because It requires a complex framework & input data that. If you could create a [mcve] (I.e. by taking the relevant function and wrapping it in a minimal main. *Complete* means that it shows the same performance behavior), then we could actually help you measure.

Comment: What are your compile options? Are you compiling with optimization such as `-O3`?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to use some performance tools such as Paraver (http://www.bsc.es/paraver), TAU (http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/home.php) Vampir (https://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/zentrale_einrichtungen/zih/forschung/projekte/vampir) or even Intel's Vtune (https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe).

These tools will help you understand where threads spends their cycles. With them, you can find whether the application is unbalanced (either by IPC or instructions), whether there is any limitation due to memory bandwidth or false sharing problems, among many other issues.